# Title name in SP online doc library

Tags: document-library

In SP online can we add a line next to doc library name, to describe the purpose of the document library. Something with different color and font with the Title name.

[image]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Don't shoot the messenger.

If you want to get fancy with SharePoint online, you will need to break out the code and develop your custom solution with SPfx

Comment: Thanks Teylyn, so with SPFx this is possible?

Comment: SPFx is a programming framework. You can write custom applications for SharePoint and make them do what you want.